Adaptive card table does not honour column width in MSTeams
EDIT 27/12
After further troubleshooting, the issue looks to be with whether the workflow is configured to post as a User or as a Workflow bot

EDIT 23/12
Issue looks to be caused by webhooks with Workflows for Microsoft Teams
When posting the below payload to a workflow, it does not render properly, but when posting to the soon to be deprecated Webhook it renders as expected.

Original post
Trying to create a table using Adaptive Cards and sending it to a webhook through a teams workflow, but no matter what I try with the table column weighting (Unless I hard code pixel widths, which defeats the purpose of adaptive) the columns do not honour the width in MSTeams, but do in the Microsoft Adaptive Card preview tool.
Not sure what I'm missing, any suggestions welcome.
I've omit some urls for images that are not relevant.
Expected behaviour:

Actual behaviour:

{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.5",
    "body": [
      {
        "columns": [
          {
            "items": [
              {
                "text": "✅ Intune Applications Created Using Local-Content (4)",
                "weight": "bolder",
                "size": "large",
                "wrap": true,
                "type": "TextBlock"
              }
            ],
            "width": "stretch",
            "type": "Column"
          },
          {
            "items": [
              {
                "url": "https://iili.io/JjeJoEx.png",
                "size": "Medium",
                "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                "type": "Image"
              }
            ],
            "width": "auto",
            "type": "Column"
          }
        ],
        "separator": true,
        "type": "ColumnSet"
      },
      {
        "columns": [
          {
            "width": "1"
          },
          {
            "width": "5"
          },
          {
            "width": "3"
          },
          {
            "width": "3"
          },
          {
            "width": "2"
          }
        ],
        "firstRowAsHeader": true,
        "gridStyle": "emphasis",
        "rows": [
          {
            "cells": [
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "",
                    "isSubtle": true,
                    "style": "heading",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Product",
                    "isSubtle": true,
                    "style": "heading",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Severity",
                    "isSubtle": true,
                    "style": "heading",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Classification",
                    "isSubtle": true,
                    "style": "heading",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "CVEs",
                    "isSubtle": true,
                    "style": "heading",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              }
            ],
            "type": "TableRow"
          },
          {
            "cells": [
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smcallister594/scotscottmca/refs/heads/main/assets/images/7-Zip.png",
                    "size": "Small",
                    "type": "Image"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "[7-Zip 24.09 (EXE-x64)](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt)",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Important",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Security",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "1",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              }
            ],
            "type": "TableRow"
          },
          {
            "cells": [
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smcallister594/scotscottmca/refs/heads/main/assets/images/7-Zip.png",
                    "size": "small",
                    "type": "Image"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "[7-Zip 24.09 (EXE-x86)](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt)",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Important",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Security",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "1",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              }
            ],
            "type": "TableRow"
          },
          {
            "cells": [
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smcallister594/scotscottmca/refs/heads/main/assets/images/7-Zip.png",
                    "size": "Small",
                    "type": "Image"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "[7-Zip 24.09 (MSI-x64)](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt)",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Important",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Security",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "1",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              }
            ],
            "type": "TableRow"
          },
          {
            "cells": [
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smcallister594/scotscottmca/refs/heads/main/assets/images/7-Zip.png",
                    "size": "Small",
                    "type": "Image"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "[7-Zip 24.09 (MSI-x86)](http://www.7-zip.org/history.txt)",
                    "wrap": true,
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Important",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "Security",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              },
              {
                "items": [
                  {
                    "text": "1",
                    "type": "TextBlock"
                  }
                ],
                "type": "TableCell"
              }
            ],
            "type": "TableRow"
          }
        ],
        "verticalCellContentAlignment": "Center",
        "separator": true,
        "type": "Table"
      },
      {
        "columns": [
          {
            "items": [
              {
                "url": "https://patchmypc.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Patch20My20PC20-20Logo20Horizontal20-20300ppi.png",
                "size": "Medium",
                "width": "180px",
                "type": "Image"
              }
            ],
            "width": "auto",
            "verticalContentAlignment": "Center",
            "type": "Column"
          },
          {
            "items": [
              {
                "text": "Report generated on **CM1**. Intune Tenant: **ScotScottMcA**",
                "size": "small",
                "isSubtle": true,
                "wrap": true,
                "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                "spacing": "None",
                "type": "TextBlock"
              },
              {
                "text": "12/20/2024 3:23:11 PM (GMT Standard Time)",
                "size": "small",
                "isSubtle": true,
                "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                "spacing": "None",
                "type": "TextBlock"
              }
            ],
            "width": "stretch",
            "verticalContentAlignment": "Center",
            "type": "Column"
          }
        ],
        "separator": true,
        "spacing": "None",
        "type": "ColumnSet"
      }
    ],
    "msteams": {
      "width": "Full"
    }
  }


We sent the above card using webhook and we see the Expected behaviour in MS Teams - https://i.sstatic.net/Jzzmrk2C.png

What version of teams are you using @Meghana-MSFT? I've tried this in multiple tenants and get the same unexpected result every time.

The client version is 1415/24120100211 - https://i.sstatic.net/xFZ1qLAi.png

interesting @Meghana-MSFT, I'm using the same version in my browser and do not see the expected result. How are you sending that payload to the webhook?

I have sent the payload using Bruno. Could you please let us know how you are sending it.

@Meghana-MSFT I'm just using CURL, nothing special.

ok, I found the issue @Meghana-MSFT! It looks like the new teams workflows, which are recommended and will replace webhooks soon, do not support Adaptive Cards properly. As soon as I post that payload directly to a webhook, with out a workflow, it renders correctly.
Can you confirm whether or not you are using workflows or just direct webhooks?

Yes, I have used webhook directly.

@Meghana-MSFT but Microsoft recommend that workflows be used in place of webhooks now, as connectors are being deprecated? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams/
Which tells me that there is some sort of feature parity missing between connectors, which you have confirmed work, and the new workflow method.
Can you please confirm whether or not this works for you using the newly recommend workflow method?

We tested this with the following workflow- https://i.sstatic.net/jtP6RULF.png. It is rendering fine with workflow as well - https://i.sstatic.net/3GY0oe4l.png. We used CURL command to post the card - https://i.sstatic.net/te2gzvyf.png

@Meghana-MSFT ok cool, getting somewhere :) I see from your screenshot that your workflow is configured as a User rather than a Workflow bot. https://i.sstatic.net/f5xw8Ys6.png. Is there any documentation on what differs between user and bot?

We are able to repro this when posted as flow bot. We raised a bug for the same, we will keep you posted on the updates. Thank you.
